# How can I most efficiently map a kernel range for a hermitian (symmetric) matrix in OpenCL?

Tags: c++, matrix, opencl

I'm working on an OpenCL project to generate very large hermitian (symmetric) matrices, and I am trying to determine the best way to generate the work IDs.

A hermitian matrix is symmetric along the diagonal, so that M(i,j) = M*(j,i).

In the brute force way, the for loop looks like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
      complex<float> result = doSomeCalculation();
      M(i,j) = result;
    }
}
```

However, taking advantage of the hermitian property, the loop can be made to be twice as efficient by only calculating the upper triangular part of the matrix and duplicating the result in the lower triangular part:

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    for(int j = i; j < N; j++)
    {
      complex<float> result = doSomeCalculation();
      M(i,j) = result;
      M(j,i) = conj(result);
    }
}
```

In both loops, doSomeCalculation() is an expensive operation, and each entry in the matrix is completely uncorrelated from every other entry (i.e. the problem is stupidly parallel).

My question is this:

**How can I implement the second loop with doSomeCalculation as an OpenCL kernel so that the thread IDs are most efficiently used (i.e. so that the thread calculates both M(i,j) and M(j,i) without having to call doSomeCalculation() twice)?**

Comment: what formula is used for the diagonal line where i==j?  is it conj(result)?

Comment: In my case, for i == j it's a special case of the scaled identity (i.e. a scalar). 

However, because the identity diagonal is purely real in a hermitian matrix, it is its own complex conjugate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a linear index, for example you can index every element of your matrix in this way:

```
0  1  2   ...  N-1
* N-2     ...  2N-2
        ....
*  * 2N-1 ...  N(N+1)/2 -1
```

That is, the index K is given by:

```
 k=iN-i*(i+1)/2+j
```

Where N is the size of the matrix and (i,j) are respectively the 0-based indices of the row and the column.

This relationship can be inverted; see the answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19143657/linear-indexing-in-symmetric-matrices) question, which I report here for completeness:

```
i = floor( ( 2*N+1 - sqrt( (2N+1)*(2N+1) - 8*k ) ) / 2 ) ;
j = k - N*i + i*(i+1)/2 ;
```

So you need to enqueue a *1D* kernel with N(N+1)/2 work items, and you can decide by yourself the size of the workgroup (usually 64 items per work group is a good choice).

Then in the OpenCL code you can retrieve the index K by using:

```
int k = get_group_id(0)*64 + get_local_id(0);
```

And then use the two relationships above the index of the matrix element you need to compute.

Moreover, notice that you can also save space by representing your hermitian matrix as a linear vector with N(N+1)/2 elements.

Comment: Thanks, however there appears to be a bug. After computing J, one needs to add I to it to get the "correct" value for J.

Answer (score 0):

If your matrices are really big, than you can dice up your NxN matrix into (N/k)x(N/k) tiles, each of size kxk. As soon as you need only a half of the data, you create **1D** NDRange of size `local_group_size * (N/k)x(N/k)/2` roughly.

[image]

Every tile of matrix is processed by one LocalGroup (size of LocalGroup is of your choice). The idea is that you create an array on Host side, which contain position of every WorkGroup in matrix. Kernel stub should look like follows:

```
void __kernel myKernel(
    __global int* coords,
    ....)
{
    int2 WorkGroupPositionInMatrix = vload2(get_group_id(0), coords);
    ...
    DoCalculation();
    ...
    WriteResultTwice();
    ...
    return;
}
```

What you need to do by hand - is to cope with thouse WorkGroups, which will be placed on the matrix diagonal. If matrix size is big, than overhead for LocalGroups, placed on diagonal is negligible.

Answer (score 0):

A right triangle can be cut in half vertically and the smaller portion rotated to fit with the larger portion to form a rectangle of equal area. Therefore it is easy to make your triangular global work area into one that is rectangular, which fits OpenCL.

See my answer here: [OpenCL efficient way to group a lower triangular matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24021305/opencl-efficient-way-to-group-a-lower-triangular-matrix)